# Joining multiple tables in Access via vba/sql

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, join

I have a database of tables, each contains two columns, the first being a code, second being an amount. The tables are pulled from data created on a daily basis, where a code will have data for a particular date if it was triggered by an external event on that date. For e.g. the table for day 2015-10-02 would look like this:

```
Code  2015-10-02
1     321.23
2     3442.13
3     679.2
4     6201.4
```

So each table has the same first column (code) but the codes will vary each day. Some days we may have different codes being triggered than any other previous day (first time it's ever been triggered) or it may have been triggered on a previous day, but with a different amount. The table I want to create will look like:

```
Code 2015-10-02 2015-10-03 2015-10-04 ....
1    321.23     0          0          
2    3442.13    0          10.42
3    679.2      41.2       0
4    294.12     41.31      1042.12
5    0          0          371.14
.
.
```

I know I could join all the tables but I want to add on any new codes as well and assume a 0 for each of the previous days the code was not triggered on.
Is there an easy way to do this via VBA/SQL?

Thanks

Comment: You want a column added each time you run your vba code?

Comment: Yep, column corresponding to the column in the table I am joining up. I'm essentially converting the individual tables into a 2d table, where the first column will consist of all codes to have triggered over the period, and the subsequent columns (with names corresponding to date) consisting of "amounts" for each day.

Comment: Access is a relational database, and when using it you are supposed to follow some design rules for your tables. Search the web for "database normalisation" (eventually normalization). You should redesign your database with a column to include the dates

Comment: You should NOT maintain separate tables for every day, nor columns with date values. This will be a management headache down the line. Heed @Kelaref's comment and Andre's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nooo. This is not how databases work.

You need a table with 3 columns, like this:

```
+------+------------+---------+
| Code |    Date    | Amount  |
+------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 2015-10-02 |  321.23 |
|    2 | 2015-10-02 | 3442.13 |
|    3 | 2015-10-02 |   679.2 |
|    4 | 2015-10-02 |  6201.4 |
|    3 | 2015-10-03 |    41.2 |
+------+------------+---------+
```

Code + Date is the primary key.

Then you can get your matrix of Code vs. Date with a **Crosstab query** (use the wizard).

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying, so I've changed the format of the tables to include the date as a field rather than a column heading. Thanks a lot for the crosstab idea, it's worked like a treat.

Comment: Apologies for the poor initial construction.

Comment: Although I did contemplate to link http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/ , an apology isn't needed. :) We're all here to learn. Glad the solution works for you. @naiminp